# How to get width of div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get width of div using jquery

`$("#window").width();` is not working

```
 <div id="widnow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#widnow{
  width:500px;
  border:solid 1px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: is it `widnow` or `window`? see http://jsfiddle.net/YLtYU/

Comment: Spelling mistake mate, rest seems fine! `$("window")` lol will fix the issue else make window to window. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It looks like you have made a simple mistake.

Try changing

```
$('#window').width();
```

to

```
$('#widnow').width();
```

From what you have displayed here, you have misspelled window as *widnow*.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

> `var width = $("#window").width();`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery Width command with the jcrop boxWidth, create a div layer around the image and then find the width using the command!

```
boxWidth: $("#cropwindow").width(),
```

this will give you the width of the responsive area!